# How to get SQL for DDL commands in Sql developer?

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

In Sql developer it is possible to get DDL for an existing table -

[image]

However, how do I get SQL for operations performed through UI? For example, how do I see DDL generated when I alter the table to drop a column? Sql developer does the drop operation and does not show me anything.

Edit:
I add a column -

[image]

And then switch over to SQL tab -

[image]

Not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle knew you wanted this feature. I'm using SQL Developer 4.0.0.13.80 and it works like you want it to.  You were probably using an older version when you posted your question.  I go to Edit Table, add a column in the GUI, and then pick the item called DDL in the dialog.  There is a radio button to show either the full CREATE statement DDL, or just the DDL update for the current edit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the table name in the left pane and select

> Table -> Generate Table API

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Look at these packages:

`DBMS_METADATA` - get_ddl function

`DBMS_METADATA_DIFF`

`DBMS_METADATA_UTIL`